# NullPointerException in static array

Tags: java, global

I want to access nodes[i] globally in every method, where am I wrong?

```
class file{
    private static java.io.File file;
    private static BufferedReader reader;
    private static int[] nodes;
    
    static {
            try {
                file = new java.io.File("/home/madhu/Desktop/readData.txt");
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(String.valueOf(file)));
                String totalNode = reader.readLine();
                String[] strs = totalNode.trim().split(",");
                 for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
                        int a = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
                        nodes[i]=a;
                 }
           } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }            
    }
    private static void level() {
        System.out.println(nodes[2]);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(nodes[2]);
    }
}
```

readData.txt contains :

```
1,2,4
```

I want to use the individual number in further calculations, so how to access it independently?

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: i am getting nullpointerexception while accessing nodes[2] .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Null pointer exception in array initialized to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605043/null-pointer-exception-in-array-initialized-to-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code never initializes the `int[] nodes`. SO you need to initialize it before the for loop as below :

```
nodes = new int[strs.length];
```

So the updated static block should be as below:

```
 static {
    try {
      file = new java.io.File("/home/madhu/Desktop/readData.txt");
      reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(String.valueOf(file)));
      final String totalNode = reader.readLine();
      final String[] strs = totalNode.trim().split(",");

      // CHANGE IS HERE
      nodes = new int[strs.length];

      for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
        final int a = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
        nodes[i] = a;
      }
    } catch (final IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

## No array created

At no point did you create an array. Think of an array as being a container with slots, like a cabinet with shelves. The shelves are empty until you fill them. But your code never built the cabinet. Your code only stated a desire to at some point own a cabinet, but never got around to making said cabinet.

Your line `private static int[] nodes;` declares a variable `nodes` that is ready and willing to refer to (point to) an array if and when some array is built.

To actually build that cabinet, that array, call `new int[] {…}`.

Change your code to something like this:

```
package work.basil.example;

public class StaticTrial
{
    private static java.io.File file;
    private static int[] nodes;

    static
    {
        StaticTrial.nodes = new int[] { 11 , 12 , 13 };  
    }

    private static void level ( )
    {
        System.out.println( nodes[ 2 ] );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println( "Running `main` method." );
        System.out.println( nodes[ 2 ] );
        System.out.println( "Ending `main` method." );
    }
}
```

…or this…

```java
package work.basil.example;

public class StaticTrial
{
    private static java.io.File file;
    private static int[] nodes = new int[] { 11 , 12 , 13 };

    private static void level ( )
    {
        System.out.println( nodes[ 2 ] );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println( "Running `main` method." );
        System.out.println( nodes[ 2 ] );
        System.out.println( "Ending `main` method." );
    }
}
```

For simplicity I am ignoring your file-loading code, as that seems irrelevant to the intent of your question. And I will sweep aside the usual cautions about thinking twice before using `static`, and I'll not explain how using `static` is not object-oriented and is fraught with risk of misuse.